# glTF Export Blender 3.3: Two Meshes with same texture/material, one correct the other black. Mesh/Object related export problem?

Tags: mesh, materials, export, gltf

When I export several objects from a scene in Blender 3.3 to glTF the texture/material of some objects are missing (or displayed incorrectly?). What really bugs me out is the fact that this happens even if (or because) several objects share the same texture/material. How can this be? And more importantly, how can I fix this?

In the example of the attached .blend-File you'll find three objects (see image). The fassade and shutters of a house and a simple cube. The former are from a scene I am currently working on and the problem seems to occur only with the fassade. As you can see, the textures/materials of the shutters and the cube are fine.

Any help is very much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model has black vertex colors applied to the "facade" object.  Try clicking the "-" icon in the "Color Attributes" panel below, to remove the vertex colors.  That should fix the problem.

[image: screenshot of Color Attributes]

Comment: Christ on a cracker, Batman! I don't know how or when I added this attribute, but deleting it solved the problem. Thank you so much for your answer. You, sir, are the best!